# Using WITH and IF in the same query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to use the `WITH` clause and `IF` statement, but it does not seem to work and I cannot find any reason why it would not. Syntax should be correct and still it is complaining about the syntax.

The error I receive is "Incorrect syntax near ';'. I have tried removing `;` characters, but then it says "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'IF'.

Is it even possible to use the WITH and IF syntax like this? The query does work without the `IF` statements (with only one of the select queries).

```
With measurements as 
        (
        (SELECT * from measurement_database1)
        UNION ALL
        (SELECT * from measurement_database2)
        UNION ALL
        (SELECT * from measurement_database3)
        );

    IF @device= 'en1' AND @other_parameter= 'yes'
        (
        select * from measurements where device like 'en1' and op like 'yes'
            );
    IF @device= 'en2' AND @other_parameter= 'no'
        (
        select * from measurements where device like 'en2' and op like 'no'
            );
    IF @device= 'en3' AND @other_parameter= 'yes'
        (
        select * from measurements where device like 'en3' and op like 'yes'
            );
```

I'm running Microsoft SQL Server 2012 11.0.6607.3.

Comment: `IF` is a T-SQL statement, but not part of SQL.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It may help you more if you think about it, not as a WITH statement but as a Common Table Expression (CTE).

That way you can go back to [the Microsoft Documents on CTEs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql#guidelines-for-creating-and-using-common-table-expressions) and read the following line;

> A CTE must be followed by a single SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE
>   statement that references some or all the CTE columns. A CTE can also
>   be specified in a CREATE VIEW statement as part of the defining SELECT
>   statement of the view.

*Although technically you can define a CTE and then not reference it at all but then what would be the point in defining it? e.g.*

```
WITH Missing AS (SELECT 'The Point' AS What)
SELECT * FROM sys.messages;
```

---

Going back to your case, you could rewrite it using `CASE` statements instead of `IF` statements but **again** what's the point? You don't need them.

You're query can be re-written to:

```
DECLARE @device char(3) = 'en3',
        @other_parameter varchar(3) = 'yes';
WITH measurements AS (
                         (SELECT    *
                          FROM  measurement_database1)
                         UNION ALL
                         (SELECT    *
                          FROM  measurement_database2)
                         UNION ALL
                         (SELECT    *
                          FROM  measurement_database3)
                     )
SELECT  *
FROM    measurements
WHERE   device LIKE @device
  AND   op LIKE @other_parameter;
```

So there's no need of `IF` statements at all!
HTH

Comment: Ah, yes. My first reaction whenever I see an `IF` in SQL is pretty much choking. My second reaction is typically to rip it out. Very, very rarely are IF statements necessarily in proper set-based SQL.

Comment: Just as an exception `WITH Missing AS (SELECT 'The Point' AS What) SELECT 'Foo'` *will* give you an error `Common table expression defined but not used.`

Comment: @MartinSmith The difference being you dropped the `FROM sys.messages;`, right? You can have unused tables you just need to use *a* table at least

Comment: @Brad - Or this also avoids the error. `WITH Missing AS (SELECT 'The Point' AS What) SELECT (SELECT 'Foo')`

Comment: @MartinSmith oh that is just weird. What's the point of the `Common table expression defined but not used.` message really then? what problem is it solving if it's so easily circumvented?

Comment: @Brad - No idea - I assume it *may* just be a simple check that happens at parse time.

Comment: @Brad Defining something that you don't ever use (and therefore don't need) is pretty bad, especially if that something requires executing a complex query. Presumably it's a (badly/lazily implemented?) warning to say "You've done something that is very obviously not correct and could have a serious impact on performance." and should take another look at it?

Comment: @AnthonyGrist, I think the point Brad was making is that the "CTE defined but not used" message doesn't *always* appear when a CTE is defined and not used.  I suppose it's still useful (ish) for it to *sometimes* appear, so long as it's not treated like an error message (where its absence would mean the bad condition doesn't exist).